# Translation of message dict into msg enum

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, enums, refactoring

I'm dealing with refactoring code which extensively uses dicts in a circumstance where enums could be used. Unfortunately, to reduce typing the dict keys were abbreviated in a cryptic fashion.
In order to have more meaningful code and fewer string literals as well as a more advanced interface I translated the message dictionary based code into an Enum based code using the same messages.

The message dictionaries looked like the following:

```
MsgDictionary = {'none': None,
                 'STJ': 'start_job',
                 'RPS': 'report_status',
                 'KLJ': 'kill_job'}

ExecStates = {'none': None,
              'JCNS': 'job_could_not_start',
              'JSS': 'job_successfully_started',
              'JSF': 'job_successfully_finished'}
```

This, unfortunately lead to cluttered code:

```
...
self.send_message(id = MsgDictionary["stj"], some_data)

...

msg = self.receive_msg()
if msg.id in (MsgDictionary['STJ'], MsgDictionary['KLJ']):
    self.toggle_job()
...
```

I would merely like to get rid of the string accesses, the cryptic names and the low level interface, like in the following. This `send_message` should send the `str` typed value of the `Enum` not the `Enum` instance itself.

```
...
self.send_message(id = MessagesEnum.START_JOB, some_data)

...

msg = self.receive_msg()
if msg.id in (MessagesEnum.START_JOB, MessagesEnum.KILL_JOB):
    self.toggle_job()
...
```

But as in the original case, undefined execution states should still be allowed. This does currently not work. The reason is to not break existing code:

```
e = ExecStates(None)
-> ValueError: None is not a valid ExecutionStates
```

And I would like to be able to compare enum instances, e.g.:

```
e = ExecState[START_JOB]
if e == ExecState[START_JOB]:
    pass

if e == ExecState[KILL_JOB]:
    pass
```

Using the following definitions, I believe I'm almost there:

```
import enum


class _BaseEnum(str, enum.Enum):
    @classmethod
    def values(cls) -> DictValues:
        return cls.__members__.values()

    def _generate_next_value_(name: str, *args: object) -> str:
        return name.lower()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)  # Use stringification to cover the None value case


class MessageEnum(_BaseEnum):
    NONE = None
    START_JOB = enum.auto()
    REPORT_STATUS = enum.auto()
    KILL_JOB = enum.auto()


class ExecutionState(_BaseEnum):
    NONE = None
    JOB_COULD_NOT_START = enum.auto()
    JOB_SUCCESSFULLY_STARTED = enum.auto()
    JOB_SUCCESSFULLY_FINISHED = enum.auto()
```

However, one problem still remains. How can I deal with `None` value as well as strings in the enumerations? In my case, all enum items gets mapped to the lowercase of the enum item name. Which is the intended functionality. However, `None` gets unintendedly mapped to `'None'`. This in effect leads to problems at other spots in the existing code which initializes an ExecutionState instance with `None`. I would like to also cover this case to not break existing code.

When I add a `__new__` method to the `_BaseEnum`,

```
def __new__(cls, value):
    obj = str.__new__(cls)
    obj._value_ = value

    return obj
```

I loose the possibility to compare the enumeration instances as all instances compare equal to ``.

My question is, in order to solve my problem, if I can corner case the `None` either in the `_generate_next_value_` or the `__new__` method or maybe using a proxy pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things that should help:

- in your `__new__`, the creation line should read `obj = str.__new__(cls, value)` -- that way each instance will compare equal to its lower-cased name
- export your enum members to the global namespace, and use `is`:

```py
    START_JOB, REPORT_STATUS, KILL_JOB = MessageEnum
    ...
    if e is START_JOB: ...
    ...
    if msg.id in (START_JOB, KILL_JOB): ...
```

Comment: Now that I see the solution, I wonder why I've overseen the obvious and forgot forwarding the value in the `__new__`. I could have guessed that from the fact that every enum member compared equal to ''.